# Laravel 6 query related to searching events not showing result when some fields are empty and some not

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm kind of new to laravel first time developing on it.
My goal is to get some filtered events to show, the filters should all work together ('filter 1' AND 'filter2' ecc..) even when some are empty.
The problem that i'm getting is that when my filter fields are empty the query won't return any event.
My CONTROLLER code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Mockery\Matcher\Not;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Nullable;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\RequestController;

class EventsController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        $eventi= Event::paginate(4);
        return view('CatalogoEventi',compact('eventi'));
    }

    public function mostraSingoloEvento($id){
        $singoloevento=Event::findOrFail($id);
        return view('PagineDinamiche/InformazioniEvento',['singoloevento'=>$singoloevento]);
    }

    public function searchEvent(){

        $data = request('data');
        $regione = request('regione');
        $societa = request('società');
        $desc = request('descrizione');

        /*
                $eventi = DB::table('users');
                if($desc!=null)
                    $eventi = $eventi->where('anteprima',$desc);
                 if($data!=null)
                     $eventi = $eventi->where('data',$data);
                if($regione!=null)
                    $eventi = $eventi->where('regione',$regione);
                if($societa!=null)
                    $eventi = $eventi->where('società',$societa);

                return view('CatalogoEventi', ['eventi'=>$eventi]); */

                 $eventi = DB::table('events')

                     ->where('anteprima','=',$desc)
                     ->where('data', '=' , $data)
                     ->where('regione', '=' , $regione)
                     ->paginate(4);

                   /* ->where('società', '=' , $societa)  */

                return view('CatalogoEventi',['eventi'=>$eventi]);


    }

    /*
    public function createEvent(){
        return redirect('/CatalogoEventi');
    }
    */

}
```

More in detail

```php
public function searchEvent(){

        $data = request('data');
        $regione = request('regione');
        $societa = request('società');
        $desc = request('descrizione');
         $eventi = DB::table('events')

                     ->where('anteprima','=',$desc)
                     ->where('data', '=' , $data)
                     ->where('regione', '=' , $regione)
                     ->paginate(4);

                return view('CatalogoEventi',['eventi'=>$eventi]);
    }
```

My view CatalogoEventi:

```html
@extends('layouts.Public')

@section('title', 'Catalogo Eventi')


<!-- CatalogoEventi -->
@section('content')
    <!-- RICERCA START  -->

<style>
    label{
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        background-image:image('/public/css/images/promo/p1.jpg') ;
        max-width: 250px;
    }
    input{
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    select{
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
    <div class="events parallax-one pad" id="events">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- default heading -->
            <div class="default-heading-shadow">
                <!-- heading -->
                <h2>Catalogo Eventi</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- events element -->
            <div class="events-element">
                <!-- BARRA DI RICERCA -->
                <!-- RICERCA -->
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <form name="Ricerca" action="/grp_15f/public/CatalogoEventi/ricerca" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                        <label for="descrizione" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Descrizione ') }}</label>
                        <input type="text" name="descrizione" id="Descrizione" placeholder="Descrizione">
                    <br><br>
                        <label for="Data" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Data ') }}</label>
                        <input type="date" name="data" id="Data" placeholder="Mese ed Anno(MM/AAAA)">
                    <br><br>

                        <label for="Regione" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Regione') }}</label>
                        <input type="text" name="regione" id="Regione" placeholder="Regione">
                    <br><br>

                        <label for="Società" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Società') }}</label>
                    <select name="società">
                        <option value="NEXT EVENTI">NEXT EVENTI</option>
                        <option value="Pincopallino srl">Pincopallino srl</option>
                        <option value="Steposkrt spa">Steposkrt spa</option>

                    </select>
                        <!-- FUNZIONE RICERCA DA IMPLEMENTARE -->
                         <input type="submit" name="tasto_cerca" value="Cerca">

                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

                <!--/ RICERCA END -->

    <!-- CATALOGO EVENTI -->
            <div class="row">

                @foreach ($eventi as $event)
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <!-- event item -->
                        <div class="events-item">
                            <!-- image container -->
                            <div class="figure">
                                <!-- event date -->
                                <div class="event-date">
                                    <!--  DA MODIFICARE -->
                                    <span class="emonth">Data: {{ $event->data }}</span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- event location -->
                                <span class="event-location"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Luogo:{{ $event->luogo }} </span>
                                <!-- image -->
                            @include('PagineDinamiche/eventImage', ['attrs' => 'imagefrm', 'imgFile' => $event->immagine])
                                <!-- image hover -->
                                <div class="img-hover">
                                    <!-- hover icon -->
                                    <a href="{{ route('infoEvento',['id'=>$event->id])  }}"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- event information -->
                            <div class="event-info">
                                <!-- event title -->
                                <h3>Titolo: {{ $event->nome }}</h3>
                                <!-- horizontal line --><hr />
                                <!-- paragraph -->
                                <p> Descrizione Breve: {!! $event->anteprima !!} </p>
                                <a href="{{  route('infoEvento',['id'=>$event->id]) }}">Scopri di piu..</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!--Paginazione-->
        @include('pagination.paginator', ['paginator' => $eventi])
    </div>

@endsection
```

My routes

```php
//CATALOGO EVENTI
Route::get('/CatalogoEventi','EventsController@index')
    ->name('catalogoEventi');

//ROTTA RICERCA
Route::any('/CatalogoEventi/ricerca','EventsController@searchEvent');
```

[result from the query abovewith field 'regione' not empty and others empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOgP0.jpg)

If i only work with this

```
$eventi = DB::table('events')

                 
                     ->where('regione', '=' , $regione)
                     ->paginate(4);
```

actually i get some results and i can display them (with some problems referring to the paginator but it's not the main problem).
I  think that i should fix the query (and i want to do this way) to get all done But for now i got no clue.

Comment: You can use `when` to add [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#conditional-clauses) e.g. `->when($desc, function ($q, $desc) { $q->where('anteprima','=',$desc); })`

Comment: @Steposkrt 
The commented code of yours is fine. Just made a few improvements.

Instead of `if($desc!=null)` use `if(isset($desc))` as in your case these viables are maynot be null but are empty string.

**or**

Instead of `if($desc!=null)` use `if(request()->filled('descrizione'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original problem is probably that the input values are not null, but rather empty strings.

But conditional queries like this are a good use of the `when()` query builder method. If the first argument evaluates to a non-false value, the second argument is executed.

```php
public function searchEvent(Request $request)
{
    $eventi = DB::table("users")
        ->when($request->descrizione, fn($q, $v) => $q->where("anteprima", $v))
        ->when($request->data, fn($q, $v) => $q->where("data", $v))
        ->when($request->regione, fn($q, $v) => $q->where("regione", $v))
            // you should rename this input to ascii just to be safe
        ->when($request->societa, fn($q, $v) => $q->where("societa", $v))
        ->paginate(4);

    return view("CatalogoEventi", compact("eventi"));
}
```

Or, if you are still on old PHP without arrow functions:

```php
public function searchEvent(Request $request)
{
    $eventi = DB::table("users")
        ->when($request->descrizione, function ($q, $v) {
            return $q->where("anteprima", $v);
        })
        ->when($request->data, function ($q, $v) {
            return $q->where("data", $v);
        })
        ->when($request->regione, function ($q, $v) {
            return $q->where("regione", $v);
        })
            // you should rename this input to ascii just to be safe
        ->when($request->societa, function ($q, $v) {
            return $q->where("societa", $v);
        })
        ->paginate(4);

    return view("CatalogoEventi", compact("eventi"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function searchEvent(){

```
    $data = request('data');
    $regione = request('regione');
    $societa = request('società');
    $desc = request('descrizione');
     $eventi = DB::table('events')

                 ->where('anteprima','=',$desc)
                 ->orWhere('data', '=' , $data)
                 ->orWhere('regione', '=' , $regione)
                 ->paginate(4);

            return view('CatalogoEventi',['eventi'=>$eventi]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$eventi = DB::table('events')
            ->when($desc, function ($q, $desc) {
                 $q->where('anteprima', 'like', '%' . request('descrizione') . '%' );
            })
```

One last thing I've updated the query part of 'descrizione' because it was comparing the strings. But actually i wanted that whenever I typed a word that was contained in the anteprima column the result was displayed.
Like anteprima='some stuff and more stuff' and I type in the "Descrizione" lablel the word 'more' the result that I should get would be the record where 'more' is contained.
With the code on top it works as I intended.
Thanks a lot for the support and sorry for my bad english sentences. :)